# Scraping title from alibaba using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrap the heading of this page i.e Yiwu City Jeweler Co. Ltd. from this link: `https://www.alibaba.com/energy-jewelrys-suppliers.html`

The html code snippet is :

```
 <a target="_blank" title href="//cnmj.en.alibaba.com/company_profile.html#top-nav-bar" data-hislog="230670293" data-domdot="id:2638,sid:230670293">Yiwu City MJ <strong>Jewelry</strong> Co., Ltd.</a>
```

i had this code:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="title ellipsis"]/a/text()').extract()
```

but the output is:

```
['Yiwu City Mj ',
 ' Jewelery',
'Co. Ltd.']
```

The problem is it should have been single item in a list not multiple items. How do i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this because of the child `strong` tags within `a`.

To fix this you can try.

```
"".join(response.xpath('//*[@class="title ellipsis"]/a//text()').extract())
```

Hope this helps the issue.